# How to display shared calendar in outlook using c#?

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, outlook, mapi

i want'to display shared calendar. i search on the web and i find this code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Outlook.Application objOLApp;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder objFolder;
        Outlook.Explorer objExplorer;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder objSubFolder;
        Outlook.AppointmentItem objCalenderItem;
        Outlook.Folders objOutlookFolders;
        int intFolderCtr;
        int intSubFolderCtr;
        int intAppointmentCtr;
        // >> Initialize The Base Objects
        objOLApp = new Outlook.Application();
        objOutlookFolders = objOLApp.Session.Folders;
        // >> Loop Through The PST Files Added n Outlook
        for (intFolderCtr = 1; intFolderCtr <= objOutlookFolders.Count; intFolderCtr++)
        {
            objFolder = objOutlookFolders[intFolderCtr];
            objExplorer = objFolder.GetExplorer();
            // >> Loop Through The Folders In The PST File
            for (intSubFolderCtr = 1; intSubFolderCtr <= objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count; intSubFolderCtr++)
            {
                objSubFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders[intSubFolderCtr];
                // >> Check if Folder Contains Appointment Items
                if (objSubFolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
                {
                    // >> Loop Through Appointment Items
                    for (intAppointmentCtr = 1; intAppointmentCtr <= objSubFolder.Items.Count; intAppointmentCtr++)
                    {
                        // >> Get Teh Calender Item From The Calender Folder
                        objCalenderItem = objSubFolder.Items[intAppointmentCtr];
                        // >> Process Appointment Item Accordingly
                        Console.WriteLine(objCalenderItem.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine(objCalenderItem.Location + "," + objCalenderItem.Start.ToLongDateString());
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // >> Close Application
       // objOLApp.Quit();
        // >> Release COM Object
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objOLApp);
        objOLApp = null;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

but it's see only my appointment.

i want to see all shared calendar. because i set meeting but i don't know any idea about other person's busy or free. so how can i display other's calendar?

editing :

i changed  this line

```
objOutlookFolders = objOLApp.Session.Folders;
```

with

```
objOutlookFolders = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Folders;
```

and i add this

```
 NameSpace oNs = objOLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
 Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(objOLApp.Session.CurrentUser.Name);
```

but i still get the error.

new version is

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Outlook.Application objOLApp;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder objFolder;
            Outlook.Explorer objExplorer;
            Outlook.MAPIFolder objSubFolder;
            Outlook.AppointmentItem objCalenderItem;
            Outlook.Folders objOutlookFolders;
            int intFolderCtr;
        int intSubFolderCtr;
        int intAppointmentCtr;
        // >> Initialize The Base Objects
        objOLApp = new Outlook.Application();



        NameSpace oNs = objOLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(objOLApp.Session.CurrentUser.Name);


        oRep.Resolve();
        //if (oRep.Resolved)
            objOutlookFolders = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).Folders;

        //else
        //    objOutlookFolders = objOLApp.Session.Folders;


        // >> Loop Through The PST Files Added n Outlook
        for (intFolderCtr = 1; intFolderCtr <= objOutlookFolders.Count; intFolderCtr++)
        {
            objFolder = objOutlookFolders[intFolderCtr];
            objExplorer = objFolder.GetExplorer();
            // >> Loop Through The Folders In The PST File
            for (intSubFolderCtr = 1; intSubFolderCtr <= objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders.Count; intSubFolderCtr++)
            {
                objSubFolder = objExplorer.CurrentFolder.Folders[intSubFolderCtr]; 
                // >> Check if Folder Contains Appointment Items
                if (objSubFolder.DefaultItemType == Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
                {
                    // >> Loop Through Appointment Items
                    for (intAppointmentCtr = 1; intAppointmentCtr <= objSubFolder.Items.Count; intAppointmentCtr++)
                    {
                        // >> Get Teh Calender Item From The Calender Folder
                        objCalenderItem = objSubFolder.Items[intAppointmentCtr];
                        // >> Process Appointment Item Accordingly
                        Console.WriteLine(objCalenderItem.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine(objCalenderItem.Location + "," + objCalenderItem.Start.ToLongDateString());
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // >> Close Application
        // objOLApp.Quit();
        // >> Release COM Object
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objOLApp);
        objOLApp = null;
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

please help me.. i'm still working. but it did not .

Answer (score 0):

Use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder to open other user's default Calendar folder.

Comment: thank's for reply. but i have one question for you. how can i use Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder? i am newwer outlook app, sorry :/

Comment: Call objOLApp.Session.CreateRecipient passing the othe rmailbox name, then pass the returned recipient to objOLApp.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(..., olFolderCalendar)

Comment: i use this methods like this 

objOutlookFolders = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
 objOutlookFolders.Display();

but i don't want to display using outlook. this method use outlook. i want to display with programmability.

Comment: I don't think I understand - your don't want to display the folder in Outlook? Then why do you call MAPIFolder.Display? Do you mean you don't want to display the folder in a separate window? Then set the Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder property.